# TeXlive 2016 "Error Message"

Tags: installing, texlive-2016

I installed TeXlive2016 on my Windows XP System and it worked without problems after this. Today I got the message (using `tlmgr update --all`):

> ```
> The installation repository does not specify a valid release year, goodbye.
> ```

I looked around but I didn’t find a hint what’s going wrong. What to do? New installation?

Comment: Run the command with the `-v` option. What does `tlmgr -v update --all` say? Does it work if you choose another repository, e.g. `tlmgr --repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet update --all`?

Comment: In the first case the gpg.exe not found and then the Message again with <C:/texlive/2016>  as name after repository. In the second case  the Message was "texlive.infra not found" with the name of the mirror. Before going into the deep I will Install again.

Comment: Also, do you by any chance have texlive 2015 installed as well? Sounds a lot like trying to update a frozen tl15

Comment: No; was a fresh installation. I will try again and see what happens.

Comment: It's 2016 and you are still running *XP*? _And_ you expect TL16 to run on it?

Comment: @Martin: I am using a Mac-system which is working fine (Thanks to the MAcUser-Group). But students of mine are using strange TeX-installations under Windows (Most of them Version 10). My recommendation was TeXlive2016 since this is a maintained system. Next step was that almost nobody was able to explain what they have done. Therfore I picked up my TP60 Lenovo system with the good XP, installed TeXlive2016 on it (it was working!!). But then over night I got the message above. Now I am installing again (it is in progress) and wait what happens.

Comment: Last comment: After re-installing everything works fine. See, what happens ..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.